# Error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [7]’ to binary ‘operator+’

Tags: c++, sql, for-loop, create-table, vertica

I am trying to create a table with variable number of columns. YH(i, Y1, Y2 ....Yd)

So I created a for loop inside the query. But it is showing the following error -

> ```
>   error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [7]’ to
>   binary ‘operator+’
>      for(int l=1;l<=d;l++) {commandline+=", Y"+ l +" real ";}
> ```

The main code is given below -

```
string commandline;
commandline = "DROP TABLE YH";
if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(hdlStmt, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.c_str()), SQL_NTS))
{
    cout<<"The drop YH table is unsuccessful."<<endl;
}

commandline = "CREATE TABLE YH"
        "(i int primary key ";
for(int l=1;l<=d;l++) {
    commandline+=", Y"+l+" real ";
}
commandline+=" ) ";
if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(hdlStmt, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.c_str()), SQL_NTS))
{
    cout<<"The create table sql command hasn't been executed successfully."<<endl;
}
```

I tried the following -

> for(int l=1;l<=d;l++) {commandline+=", Y" l " real ";}
>
> for(int l=1;l<=d;l++) {commandline+=", Y"+std::string(l)+" real ";}

None of them seems to be working.

Comment: If you want to use double-quotes " in your SQL statements, escape them properly by using \". Also, make sure that your SQL statements are checked against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Jodocus Where do see him trying to use double quotes in the SQL statement?

Comment: Oops, I missed that! `commandline+=std::string(", Y") + std::to_string(l) + " real ";` Or as @user4581301 says, use `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Also `", Y"+l` has some really interesting and probably unexpected effects that are worth pointing out. `", Y"` is what's called a string literal. It's represented as a constant array of `char`. Adding a number to an array increments where you look at the array rather than appending a number to the array. Here's an example of what happens: https://ideone.com/3Dk3df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `+` to concatenate an integer to a string. When you write

```
", Y" + l
```

it adds `l` to the pointer to the string literal, and that just returns another pointer. Then when you do `+ " real"` it tries to add the pointer to that array, but there's no such overload for the `+` operator. `+` can only be used for concatenation when at least one of the arguments is a `std::string`.

`std::string(l)` doesn't work, either. That's not how you get the string representation of a number. The function you want is `std::to_string(l)`.

```
commandline += ", Y" + std::to_string(l) + " real ";
```

Comment: it says ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: What version of C++ are you using? `std::to_string` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: I changed it to c++11. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative pre C++11 approach:

[Documentation on `std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

In a nutshell, `ostringstream` allows your program to write into a self-resizing buffer that easily converts to a `string` the same way you would write into any other any other input stream. Like `cout`, for example.

```
// create the ostringstream around the initial string data
ostringstream commandline("CREATE TABLE YH (i int primary key ");
for(int l=1;l<=d;l++) {
    // write into the ostringstream. l will automatically be converted from a number
    commandline << ", Y" << l <<" real ";
}
commandline << " ) ";

// (str() gets the string from the ostringstream. 
// c_str() converts this string into a character array
if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(hdlStmt, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.str().c_str()), SQL_NTS))
{
    cout<<"The create table sql command hasn't been executed successfully."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ostringstream`?

Comment: Fud. Thanks. Fixing.

Comment: Man, I followed that screw-up all the way through to `cin`. Definitely past bedtime.